# Assigning class to base class, how do do it?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm confused about assigning the base object of a derived class. Say I have a type:

```
class Base {
 // stuff omitted for brevity
}
```

and a derived class

```
Derived : public Base {
  // stuff omitted
}
```

and I have a situation that arises like this:

```
Derived = Base;
```

Is this possible? What is this operation called? How would I do such a thing?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfectly ordinary user-defined assignment that looks enough like "slicing", treating a base class as if it were a member, to confuse the unwary.  But it's not slicing. For the situation you have, the two classes might as well not be related, and you define the assignment that way.

```
struct d : b {
     d &operator=(const b &b_) { /*do the work here*/; return *this; }
};
```

You might be able to use the base class's copy-assignment operator, or you might not:

```
struct dx : b {
    dx &operator=(const b &b_)
    {
        this->b::operator=(b_);
        // more work
        return *this;
    }
};
```

but the compiler gives this no special treatment, it's the same as any function call.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I figured I could do this with an assignment operator but just wanted to make sure it was appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You should almost never assign a base class object to a derived class object, because then a derived object is only partly assigned which may not be consistent. But there are times that you may need to cast a pointer of a base class object to a pointer of a derived class object

```
Base *pb = new Derived;
..
Derived *pd = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pb);
```

This is used when you want to identify the exact type of the object pointed by a base pointer(but actually pointing to the drived object, like in this example). Usually you should avoid this because it's time-consuming, and it's not a good design.

Comment: @TylerJandreau Better is for you to ask what you are actually trying to do, rather than specific solution that is probably not a good one.

Answer (score 0):

This is called `object slicing` and it is usually a bad thing. A Derived class is a Base class with more stuff. So when you assign a Derived object to a Base object, what should happen to the extra stuff? The operation doesn't make logical sense.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the class `Base` has a copy-assignment operator in the first place, you want to call that method of a "modifiable reference to `Base`" obtained from an object `d` of type `Derived`. Normally the compiler will happily (and silently) provide the required up-cast when `d` is used in a context that requires such a base reference (for instance as an argument to a function expecting that), but here there is no such context. So it suffices to supply such a context using a `static_cast`:

```
static_cast<Base&>(d) = b;
```

will do the job.